# Reassembling a fragmented image

Tags: image, image-processing

I have an image that has been broken in to parts, 64 rows by 64 columns. Each image is 256x256px. The images are all PNG. They are named "Image--.png" for example "Image-3-57". The rows and columns numbering start from 0 rather than 1.

How can I assemble this back in to one image? Ideally using BASH and tools (I'm a sysadmin) though PHP would be acceptable as well.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck on http://superuser.stackexchange.com/ if you want a bash command to do it. You can probably have a look at imagemagick, I'm pretty sure it's possible to use it for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not very complicated, if you want to use PHP. What you need is just a few image gunctions - [imagecreate](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) and [imagecopy](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php). If your PNG is semi transparent, you will also need [imagefilledrectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) to create a transparent background.
In code below, I rely on fact, that all chunks are same size - so the pixel size must be able to be divided by the number of chunks.

```
<?php
$width = 256*64;    //height of the big image, pixels
$height = 256*64;
$chunks_X = 64;  //Number of chunks
$chunks_Y = 64;  //Same for Y
$chuk_size_X = $width/$chunks_X;  //Compute size of one chunk, will be needed in copying
$chuk_size_Y = $height/$chunks_Y;

$big = imagecreate($width, $height);   //Create the big one
for($y=0; $y<$chunks_Y; $y++) {
  for($x=0; $x<chunks_X; $x++) {
    $chunk = imagecreatefrompng("Image-$x-$y.png");
    imagecopy($big, $chunk, 
              $x*$chuk_size_X,    //position where to place little image    
              $y*$chuk_size_Y,
              0,                  //where to copy from on little image
              0,
              $chuk_size_X,       //size of the copyed area - whole little image here
              $chuk_size_Y,
    );
    imagedestroy($chunk);        //Don't forget to clear memory
  }
}
?>
```

This is just a draft. I'm not sure about all theese xs and ys as well as ather details. It is late and I'm tired.